# Why is SimpleXMLElement undefined despite allow_url_fopen and simpleXML being enabled in php.ini?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

My code just returns this:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function SimpleXMLElement() in
>   /path/to/xmltest.php
>   on line 6

And the code itself:

```
<?php
$language_url = "http://www.fakesite.com/api/FAKEAPIKEY/languages.xml";

// Passing the XML
$data = file_get_contents($language_url);
$books = SimpleXMLElement($data);

//-------------------
// Passing a filename
//$books = SimpleXMLElement($language_url, null, true);
?>
```

Naturally, `$language_url` is valid, but I changed it for privacy concerns. It resides on a different site from which I'm trying to run this script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SimpleXMLElement` is a class for simplexml,
you should instantiate it like the usual object :-

```
$books = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
```

Or the procedural function

```
 $books = simplexml_load_string($data); // load from string
 $books = simplexml_load_file($url);   // load from file
```

Comment: doing the first suggesting gave another error saying simpleexmlelement requires at least one parameter. I'll try the other suggestions.

Comment: You really have to read the manual, and I already update `;` to `(...);`

Comment: With that update (which came after my comment, and not before) things are working properly again. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also, you're missing a paren on  $books = simplexml_load_string$data);

Answer (score 2):

Is the SimpleXML library loaded? Look throu your php.ini for a line saying `;extension=simplexml.so` and remove the semicolon. Restart your http service and it should work.

Comment: I added that first, and the change seemed to be reflected in phpinfo not sure how to restart http service on my host. I'll look into it.

Comment: Yeah you'll have to restart the service for those changes to take effect.  Do you have root shell access on the server? If so try typing /etc/init.d/httpd restart or alternately /etc/init.d/apache2 restart